# Java Multi-Threading with global variables

Tags: java, multithreading

Apologies in advance, since this seems to be a pretty common question, but none of the answers I've found so far were able to help me. (Not even sure if I'm searching for the right thing, to be honest)

I'm writing a program which is supposed to update Firmware for Servers (and their components)
These servers have Mellanox-Cards built in (ConnectX5 for anyone that might know these) which need to have their firmware up/down-graded. In order to speed up this process, I've decided to put this update process into multiple threads, so I can start them at the same time and only continue with the program until all threads have completed their work.

Here is my code so far:

```
final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(mellanox.size()+1);
ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(mellanox.size());
for (int index = 0; index < mellanox.size(); index++) {
    String mellanoxCard = mellanox.get(index);
    String ip = ipAddresses.get(index);
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            if (isWindows) {
                builder.command(flint, "-d", mellanoxCard, "-i", mellanoxFWPath, "-y", "burn");
                setupLoading.setProgressInfo("Updating Mellanox FW for System " + ip, "calibri");
                gate.await();
                startProcess();
                latch.countDown();
                setupLoading.setProgressInfo(streamGobbler.getResult(), "consolas");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            setupLoading.setProgressInfo("An error has occured during Mellanox Firmware update!", "warning");
            writeErrorLog(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
    threads.add(t);
}
for(Thread t : threads) t.start();
try {
    gate.await();
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
    writeErrorLog(e.getMessage());
}
```

Since it's probably hard to create a minimal reproducible example (at least not without buying a Server with a mellanox card) I'll try and break this down as best as possible.

The problem I'm having is the following: When testing this with 4 systems, flint (the software used to do the firmware upgrade) responds with:

```
-E- Cannot open Device: 192.168.4.150#23108,mt4119pciconf0. No such device MFE_CR_ERROR
-E- Cannot open Device: 192.168.4.150#23108,mt4119pciconf0. No such device MFE_CR_ERROR
-E- Cannot open Device: 192.168.4.150#23108,mt4119pciconf0. No such device MFE_CR_ERROR
```

But not a fourth time. I'm almost 99% certain that for some reason, the threads all take on the same values, and flint tries to do the update 4 times on the same system, instead of once on each system, causing this "no such device" error to appear, since the device is already in use.

So, in order to test this theory, I started debugging. After all threads were created, I checked the arguments for each of them, and every thread had a different `mellanoxCard`.
Since I wasn't able to find the full `builder.command` I also double checked if the `ip` was a different one for each thread as well - which it was. It also printed out the messages fine, and each of them had a different `ip`.
But after letting the threads proceed, I still got the same error 3 times.

I am honestly stumped as to what might be the problem here, or google for, so any pointers in any direction are greatly appreciated. I suspect that it might have something to do with the way I create the Threads/handle the variables, hence the Question title, but as far as I know it could be anything.

Thanks! ♥

Comment: Unrelated: why on earth are you using raw Thread objects. Your code looks like it was written 10, 15 years ago. Current day java has a ton of abstractions that allow you to write multi threaded code almost without ever using the word "thread" in your code. Seriously: for real world production code, step back, and do some research how to write decent multi threading code with Java in 2021.

Comment: The error message you posted... Does the IP address change with each message?

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the suggestion. Do you by any chance have a learning source which you could recommend? Whenever I search for "java how to multi-thread" or along these lines, the tutorials always use the Thread class, or create their own which extends/implements the Thread/Runnable class. What classes would you recommend instead of the Thread class?

Comment: Aside: What you are doing looks like the kind of problem `Cron` was invented for

Comment: @ControlAltDel apologies, the way I worded it is a bit confusing. The IP address doesn't change with each message, it always stays the same

Comment: @Korlimann "... it always stays the same". Sounds like you are updating the same system four times, with all but the first unable to execute because the first is already running. You want this to be updating different systems, right?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Yes, that is my theory on why it's not working properly. I just couldn't figure out yet what, or rather how it went wrong. Is there maybe a different way to assign the variables?

Comment: You appear to be using a single ProcessBuilder instance in multiple threads.  [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) explicitly states that ProcessBuilder is not thread-safe.

Comment: @VGR that actually makes a ton of sense, thank you so much. Is there an alternative to the ProcessBuilder I should use, or would it suffice to create a new instance of the ProcessBuilder for each thread?

Comment: Create a new ProcessBuilder in each thread.  It’s not that expensive.

Comment: My advice: I think you are over-complicating this problem in using  Java. Management isn't going to care about multi-threaded performance... unless it doesn't work and systems aren't updated. Build something simple (with a technology - like a batch script - at a higher level than Java, if possible), something that the next one who picks this code up after you can look at and easily understand. This is usually much more important than runtime performance

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html for example. Go research terms like Future or CompletableFuture.